# Warning: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\laravel\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

## Environement

- Windows 7
- WAMP server

  - PHP 5.3.13
  - Apache 2.2.12
  - MySQL 5.5.24
- Laravel 4.1

I installed laravel, trying to run the URL

```
http://localhost/laravel/public
```

**autoload.php**

```
define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

if (file_exists($compiled = __DIR__.'/compiled.php')){
    require $compiled;
}

Illuminate\Support\ClassLoader::register();

if (is_dir($workbench = __DIR__.'/../workbench')){
    Illuminate\Workbench\Starter::start($workbench);
}
```

I am facing the following errors:

> Warning: require(C:\wamp\www\laravel\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\laravel\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

and

> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'C:\wamp\www\laravel\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\laravel\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Comment: Your anchor's `href` is supposed to contain a file name =,= can you paste the code of `autoload.php`?

Comment: i have pasted the code of autoload.php user007

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Go to the current Project folder

```
C:\wamp\www\laravelProjectFolder>
```

and type `composer install` in command prompt and press `ENTER` key.

```
composer install
```

Then the `vendor` directory will be downloaded in the current project of laravel.
Now refresh the screen.

Comment: no i just have 5.2 laravel project and then copy my app folder and models and migrations and views and public folder into 7.2 laravel and after edit serviceproviders this command (php artisan serve) did run and this error appeared

Answer (score 2):

Simply make your storage folder writable. This can be found in your app directory

In your terminal use this command

```
chmod +w <directory> or chmod a+w <directory>
```

Make sure you navigate to the directory containing the directory you want to make writable or you point to that path.

Answer (score 0):

go to your project folder via cmd. run the following command

```
composer update
```

it will install missing vendor folder and files in your project.

but in some cases it gives error like " Your configuration does not allow connection to bla bla bla.."

for that go to your **composer.json** file,

change `"secure-http": true` to `"secure-http": false`

but in some cases (as was in my case) you may not find such line in your file. for that do the following action:

change `"config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }`

to

```
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "secure-http": false
}
```

and run again `composer update` command.

hope this will solve problem of many persons. :)

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to include:

```
C:\wamp\www\laravel\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php
```

and the error gives

```
No such file or directory in 
         C:\wamp\www\laravel\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
```

so you need to check your directory layout. Is there a directory `vendor` in `lavarel` with a file `autoload.php` in it?

and you should either have `/` in your pathnames or `\` but not mixed both.