# No such file or directory in ...vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:444 (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, exception, classloader, handler

I'm writing a code in Laravel. When I try to make a post with a file in the form, it will throw the following exception:

> Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: include(/var/www/vhosts/web2/httpdocs/vendor/composer/../../app/Exceptions/Handler.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/web2/httpdocs/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:444\nStack trace:\n#0 
>   .
>   .
>   .
>
> n#5 /var/www/vhosts/web2/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(803): ReflectionClass->__construct('App\...', referer: (hidden)

add.blade.php:

```
@include('flash::message')
<form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{action('SheetController@add')}}" method="post">
@csrf
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="icao">ICAO</label>  
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <input placeholder="i.e. SAAC" class="form-control input-md" id="icao" name="icao" type="text" required />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="fir">FIR</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="fir" name="fir" class="form-control input-md" required>
    <option value="SAEF">Ezeiza</option>
    <option value="SACF">C&oacute;rdoba</option>
    <option value="SAMF">Mendoza</option>
    <option value="SAVF">Comodoro Rivadavia</option>
    <option value="SARR">Resistencia</option>
   </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="version">Version</label>  
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <input placeholder="i.e. 1.2" class="form-control input-md" id="version" name="version" type="text" required />
  </div>
</div>

<!-- File input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="sheetfile">Archivo</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input id="sheetfile" name="sheetfile" class="form-control input-md" required type="file">
  </div>
</div>

<hr style="margin-bottom:20px;">

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
    <input type="reset" class="btn btn-warning" value="Reset" />
  </div>
</div>

</form>
```

SheetController.php:

```
public function add(Request $request)
{
    if(!empty($request->all()))
    {
        $sheet = new Sheet();
        $sheet->icao = $request->icao;
        $sheet->fir = $request->fir;
        $sheet->version = $request->version;

        $newName = $sheet->icao.'_v'.$sheet->version.'.pdf';

        if($request->file('sheetfile')->getClientOriginalExtension() != 'pdf')
        {
            flash()->error('File not allowed')->important();
        }
        else if($request->imagen->storeAs('ATC/Sheets', $newName, 'files'))
        {
            if($sheet->save()) flash()->success('Sheet added')->important();
            else flash()->error($sheet->errors()->first())->important();
        }
        else flash()->error('The file could not be uploaded.')->important();
    }
    return redirect()->action('SheetController@list');
}
```

I have already tried `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload`

Any ideas?

Comment: Remove `/vendor` folder, then run composer du and try again. Make sure you have no custom code in `/vendor`

Comment: doesn't work:

\bootstrap\app.php on line 14
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in \boot
#0 \artisan(20): require_once()
#1 {main}
  thrown in strap\app.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 \artisan(20): require_once()
#1 {main}
  thrown in \bootstrap\app.php on line 14
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255

Comment: I think `composer du` uses some scripts in vendor folder

Comment: Silly me. Use `composer install` after deleting `vendor` folder

Comment: If that doesn't work still, I strongly believe you're using an outdated version of composer, or `package.json` is corrupted. Try to install the latest version of composer, then repeat the steps

Comment: it worked, but the browser still shows 500 error, for some reason. I tried the database and file sections separately, and it still shows 500 error. both sections work on a different script. I'm confused.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\laravel\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363829/warning-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory-in-c-wamp-www-laravel)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply do the,

```
composer update
```

It's working fine for me.

Comment: Quite correctly expressed .

Answer (score 1):

Just doing

```
composer dump-autoload
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed using this artisan commands

```sh
    php artisan cache:clear 
    php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

If the composer dump-autoload won't work for you, then the error tells you that a directory is missing in my case, there was no migrations folder inside the database directory.

Solution: Create the migrations folder inside the database directory. You can do this using your IDE, or Windows's File Explorer. If your using Git Bash, cd to your project's database folder then do mkdir migrations to create the missing migrations directory.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the vendor folder and do composer install.

Answer (score -1):

You can try;

```
composer dump-autoload
```

inside the root folder.

Comment: I already tried that. If I try the database part, it works perfectly, but I think the issue is the file part

Comment: Ok, I finally resolved the issue. It was a programming mistake.

Comment: $request->imagen does not exist. It must be $request->sheetfile haha

Comment: Thanks for your help guys anyway

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer - why should that be tried? Keep in mind that others should be able to learn from your answer